# Which color is #0000?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to guess which color is #0000

In the following code:

> $('.example').css({"background-color":"#0000","opacity": "0.20", "filter": "alpha(opacity=20)" 
>                         });

Replacing #0000 by any of the following colors don't produce the same effect:

`#0000FF, #FF0000, #00FF00, #000000, #00000, #000`

I thought any 3 o 4 digit color had a corresponding 6 digit color. I'm I wrong?

Comment: `#0000` is an invalid hex color afaik.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-color/#hex-notation:

> #### 4 digits
>
> This is a shorter variant of the 8-digit notation, "expanded" in the
>   same way as the 3-digit notation is. The first digit, interpreted as a
>   hexadecimal number, specifies the red channel of the color, where 0
>   represents the minimum value and f represents the maximum. The next
>   three digits represent the green, blue, and alpha channels,
>   respectively.

transparent, like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)`

not supported yet tho. From http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#parsing-errors:

> **Illegal values.** User agents must ignore a declaration with an illegal value.

Here's a testcase. Yellow background = not supported. Transparent (white) background = supported.

http://jsfiddle.net/p5aJJ/

```
<div class="test">hello</div>
```

...

```
div {
    background-color: yellow;
}

div.test {
    background-color: #0000;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. But does any browser support it yet? It is an invalid color on my Canary.

Comment: This is CSS4 (in other words, a draft).

Comment: That's a godd answer! Is this, however, supported in all major browsers? I've never seen this notation in actual use and jsFiddle treats it as a sintax error: http://jsfiddle.net/D8rUr/1/ (notice how #000000 is highlighted with a blue color, but #0000 with red).

Comment: @AlexB. You should specify an alpha channel different than 0 to have a visible result, but yes, it is interpreted as an invalid value in Chrome Canary and Firefox Nightly.

Comment: thanks, I've added some information on how CSS handles illegal values